# ASP.NET Core MVC - Refreshing single elements & constantly reading RFID data/updating databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, rfid

I´m working on a project and tried to implement two different things without any success.

1. I want to refresh multiple tables on my pages without refreshing the whole page. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />` works but isnt as elegant as I want it to.
2. I have to constantly read a RFID-Chip and based on the data I need to update my databases. I have no idea how to a) read it constantly and b) update all databases without the pages opened.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: 1. you need to make ajax call 2. a bit unclear

Comment: 2. but assuming you want to read RFID and send its data to database without having your browser open, you need some how to make a background service (not browser based) that scan and update your database.

Comment: `I want to refresh multiple tables on my pages without refreshing the whole page.`Maybe you can try to use ajax and partial view.

Comment: Okay so can you give me some more information to this ajax call? I´m pretty new in this area and have no idea how it works/it´s done (i will research it meanwhile).

Comment: And for the second point: So I have to make another program which reads the data and contributes the databases and my web application just takes the information from this program?